# how to access rails helper method current_user inside rails job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have the following code inside a Rails job:

```
class MessageBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(message)
   ActionCable.server.broadcast "room_channel", message: render_message(message),msg: message, user: current_user
  end

  private
  def render_message(message)
    ApplicationController.renderer.render(partial: 'messages/message', locals: { message: message})
   end
end
```

As you can see, I want to pass `current_user`, but I can't access the devise Rails helper method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Devise helper methods are not available in ActiveJobs, what you can do instead is pass the current_user id to the perform method, and fetch the user there e.g.

```
def perform(message, current_user_id)
  current_user = User.find(current_user_id)
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "room_channel", message: render_message(message),msg: message, user: current_user
end
```